# How can I get more verbose messages from a GP service?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, rest

When I run a tool I've published as a gp service, the only messages I get are these:

```
esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Submitted. 
esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Executing... 
esriJobMessageTypeInformative: Succeeded.
```

Is there some way I can get the same messages I see when I run the tool locally?

I don't see anything obvious in [the documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/gpjob.html).

It is a custom tool written in arcobjects (implementing IGPFunction), so if there's some special way to call [IGpMessages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGPMessages_Interface/0025000003wt000000/) I'd consider that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "showMessages" option in your service config file?

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//0093000000mr000000.htm

If it's "false" (the default) then ArcGIS Server will swallow all the messages.

Comment: Thanks mwalker, was able to stop the service and check the "show messages" checkbox in ArcCatalog.